# Python Reversing List Using Slicing

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a function that reverses and mutates a list via **slicing/appending** without using `[::-1]` or `.reverse()`. I am looking for any additional resources online but it seems to be the only two popular reserving techniques. 
Can anyone help me think of how I can write this?

Comment: Old fashion `for i in range(len(list)-1, 0, -1):`?

Comment: Use `for` loop to iterate over index backward and append the elements

Comment: I'm trying to think of how I would do this with a list of unspecified length

Comment: apart from [::-1] and .reverse() there is another built in function called reversed()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try:

```
n = len(a)
for i in range(n):
    a.append(a[n - (i+1)])
a = a[n:]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can do it:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [0]*len(a)

for i in range(len(a)):
    b[len(a) - 1 - i] = a[i]
print(b)
```